# Adding a Filter and Init Params Progmatically

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters, yahoo-finance

I need to copy the contents of a web.xml to the WebAppInitializer.class (Java Configuration Class).  I have copied the YahooFilter Class from web.xml (see code) but I am not sure how to add the init-params pragmatically.

I have pasted the web.xml and snippet of the Java Configuration class below. Can somebody take a look and provide some feedback?

```
<web-app> 
     <display-name>sample</display-Aname> 
     <filter> 
         <filter-name>YOSFilter</filter-name> 
         <filter-class>com.yahoo.yos.YahooFilter</filter-class> 


         <!--  
         optional param - 
         underlying oauth client class 
         possible values: 
             net.oauth.client.URLConnectionClient (default) 
             net.oauth.client.httpclient3.HttpClient3 
             net.oauth.client.httpclient4.HttpClient4 
         --> 
         <init-param> 
             <param-name>oauthConnectionClass</param-name> 
             <param-value>net.oauth.client.httpclient4.HttpClient4</param-value> 
         </init-param> 
         <!--  
         optional param - 
         redirect end-user if an access token is not found, set to false if you  
         are only making two-legged oauth calls e.g. oauth calls without an  
         access token to retrieve public information 
         defauts to true 
         --> 
         <init-param> 
             <param-name>redirect</param-name> 
             <param-value>true</param-value> 
         </init-param> 
     </filter> 


     <!-- 
     The URL where the filter is mapped to will redirect the user to Yahoo for 
     authorization if an OAuth authorization token has not been obtained for the 
     user.  Should correspond to your callback url 
     --> 


     <filter-mapping> 
         <filter-name>YOSFilter</filter-name> 
         <url-pattern>/login.jsp</url-pattern> 
     </filter-mapping> 
 </web-app>
```

Java Config Class

```
    public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
     ...

            @Override
        protected void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
                    super.registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);
            servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());

           // servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());      
        }

             @Override
            protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
                     DelegatingFilterProxy delegatingFilterProxy =  new DelegatingFilterProxy();
                    delegatingFilterProxy.setTargetBeanName("springSecurityFilterChain");
                    // FilterConfig filterConfig = delegatingFilterProxy.getFilterConfig();

                     YahooFilter yosFilter = new YahooFilter();


                    return  new Filter[] {delegatingFilterProxy,yosFilter};
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try overriding `onStartup()` method and programatically register your filter with `ServletContext` like this:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    FilterRegistration yahooFilter = servletContext.addFilter("yahooFilter", new YahooFilter());
    yahooFilter.setInitParameter("oauthConnectionClass", "net.oauth.client.httpclient4.HttpClient4");
    yahooFilter.setInitParameter("redirect", "true");
}
```

Comment: @Bohuslav_Burghardt Is this answer meant to be in addition to or instead of what the original poster is doing in his getServletFilters() code?  And if the answer is "in addition to" then what is the relation between yahooFilter and yosFilter?

Comment: @SteveCohen OP adds filters in `getServletFilters` method, which just produces array of `Filter` objects. My solution involves registering the filter via servlet context in `onStartup` method which returns [`FilterRegistration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/FilterRegistration.html) object allowing to set init parameters. This solution is therefore "instead" of the original one, not "in addition". The yahooFilter instead of yosFilter is just a name which seemed more logical to me.

Comment: I get init parameter in filter as `null`, can you show example of handling redirect in the filter?