# Spring - Send parameter(s) per url mapping to same Filter

Tags: java, spring, servlet-filters

I have Spring application deployed on Tomcat,

I'm adding a [OncePerRequestFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456982/onceperrequestfilter-unable-to-set-error-code-different-than-404)

```
@Component
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private String id;    
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyFilter.class);
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
       logger.debug("Filter id: " + id);
```

to specific URLs

```
FilterRegistration myFilter = servletContext.addFilter("myFilter ", MyFilter.class);
myFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/myservlet/myendpoint/*");
myFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/myservlet/myendpoint2/*");
myFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/myservlet/myendpoint3/*");
```

I want different behavior for different url mapping with using same class, so I need to send parameter, for example String, that will be available in Filter class and will execute different check, can this be done with current configuration?

I tried with add [init parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961998/adding-a-filter-and-init-params-progmatically), but id is `null` in Filter

```
myFilter.setInitParameter("id", "1");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 options:

1. **Option 1**: 
   Basically you need to overwrite the ***public void initFilterBean()*** and set your bean properties
2. **Option 2**: The MyFilter component is a Spring fully-manage bean so another way to set the id property would be using it as a
   property *(specify a property value for my-filter.id in your
   application properties file, for this to work you'll need to obtain
   a reference to the myFilter instance from the Spring
   ApplicationContext container)*:

   ```
   @Value("my-filter.id") 
   private String id;
   ```

Comment: 1 - I'm getting `Cannot override the final method from GenericFilterBean`

Comment: 2- I want to set different values for different paths

Comment: I didn't know Spring made final the init method on its implementation, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Can you show example of updated 1? I don't have filterconfig available in new method

Comment: Use this.getFilterConfig()